# Crash using movapd with aligned memory

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, simd, memory-alignment

I have a block of memory allocated with `malloc` using 64 bit NASM on Windows.  When I use *movapd* (move two aligned packed double-precision floating-point values), my program crashes, but I can use *movupd* (move two unaligned packed double-precision floating-point values).

I changed to `_aligned_malloc` specifying alignment=16, which works to allocate memory, but I still get an error when I use *movapd*. Prior to the instructions executing my debugger shows *R8*=0xB0FC78, *R15*=0x12FC0050, *RCX*=0x6D40050, and *RDX*=0x10010050. *RCX* and *RDX* are pointers to the two memory blocks. *R8* and *RCX* are counters across the blocks

This works:

```
movupd xmm0,[rdx+r8]
movupd [r15+rcx],xmm0
```

This crashes:

```
movapd xmm0,[rdx+r8]
movapd [r15+rcx],xmm0
```

Oddly, the program is slower with `_aligned_malloc` than with malloc'd memory.

My code is written in NASM (assembly language), but I don't think the language matters.

Why can't I use *movapd* even with memory allocated with `_aligned_malloc`?

Comment: Just prior to these instructions executing what are the values the debugger says are in rdx, r8, r15, and rcx? I can only guess that when rdx+r8 and/or r15+rcx are computed that the resulting address is not properly aligned.

Comment: I'm getting that info now.  I'll be back in a few minutes.

Comment: The final effective address must not be aligned.  There's no setting that will make `movapd` crash but `movupd` succeed other than alignment.  Use your debugger.  Did you forget to scale array offsets by `sizeof(double) = 8` or something?

Comment: r8 11598968
r15 318505040
rcx 114557008
rdx 268501072

Comment: I didn't pass an array offset.  The spec only calls for two inputs, but in one C++ example, it shows the second parameter consisting of alignment and offset.  In NASM, I could do that as a pointer to a two-element array, which I will try now.

Comment: I see that r8 is not aligned on a 16-byte boundary.  The others are.  These instructions all relate to pointers to memory that is aligned.

Comment: Easier to read in HEX. r8=B0FC78, r15=12FC0050 rcx=6D40050 rdx=10010050

Comment: r8 doesn't have 0 as its last nibble (last 4 bits) so it will break alignment when added to rdx which is aligned.(lower nibble of rdx is 0)

Comment: Then that's what I need to work on.  rcx and rdx are pointers to the two memory blocks; r8 and rcx are counters across the blocks.

Comment: So `r8` and `rcx` *are* byte offsets into the arrays, like I was guessing.  (But they are scaled to multiples of 8, you just forgot to ensure that they were multiples of 16 for alignment).  IDK why you'd want to use indexed addressing modes instead of just incrementing pointers by 8 though, since you're using two different counters anyway.  Indexed addressing modes have extra cost on some microarchitectures.  (Indexed stores can't use port 7 on Haswell+, or will un-laminate on SnB/IvB).  Indexing is mostly useful when you can use the same index for multiple bases.

Comment: If you don't already know this, writing in C with intrinsics will probably make code that's at least as good.  (Most compilers don't seem to know this either, so they often won't do better, but they will often choose to use pointer increments when they can't use the same index for multiple arrays.)

Comment: One question you may know the answer to.  Is there any way to pass the four small buffers back to the calling program as one buffer (this is a dll) without going through the step of combining them.  I suspect the answer is no unless they happen to be contiguous in memory, but I can't rely on that.  The combining process is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to this question in this particular case.  After multicore processing, I have four small buffers to combine into one large buffer.  I'm using SIMD to speed up the process.

Below are the register values passed into the final step (combining), divided by 16.

7024645     0   714474.5    19906565              0 THREAD 1

10285061        0   728618  19906565 714474.5       THREAD 2

13414405        0   726064.5 19906565 1443092.5 THREAD 3

16781317        0   724936  19906565 2169157        THREAD 4

The third and fifth columns show values that do not divide evenly by 16, so I can't use aligned access.  The third column is the size of the small buffer for that thread.  The reason for the "misalignment" is because the program returns an unequal number of quadwords for each segment, which means the final output may or may not end on an even multiple of 16 -- as a simple example, if I have three quadwords (24 bytes), that doesn't divide evenly by 16.

According to this blog post, memory alignment does not significantly affect performance on the most recent processors:  https://lemire.me/blog/2012/05/31/data-alignment-for-speed-myth-or-reality/

I'd be interested in any comments on that.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The blog you linked is testing scalar integer code.  It's true that the penalty for cache-line splits is low-ish on Nehalem / Bulldozer and later, but being able to fold a memory operand into an ALU instruction (like `addpd xmm0, [rdi]`) can save uops vs. a separate `movupd` that's requires for potentially-unaligned data unless you have AVX.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question at all.  The double-precision numbers in xmm0 / memory don't have to be divisible by 16, their addresses do.  Addresses are integers, so clearly `714474.5` isn't a pointer or address.  And if you have 24 bytes of data, you'd use `movapd` for the first 16 and `movsd` for the last 8.

Comment: When we combine four buffers into one, the startbyte into the large buffer will be the previous startbyte plus the length of the previous small buffer.  If the preceding small buffer does not end on an even multiple of 16, the startbyte of the large buffer will be misaligned (as it is here).  The pointer adddress 714474.5 is 11431592 divided by 16.

Comment: Naturally I would like to use aligned access, but I don't see how I can do that here.

Comment: Oh I see.  That was very unclear.  You talked about having 4 small buffers, but then you have 5 columns.  Each thread actually has 5 buffers and some of them are NULL?  And you showed base 10 fractions, which again is totally weird for pointers.  You didn't say *which* registers you were talking about.

Comment: The columns correspond to registers rdx, r8, r9 and r15.  (1) Pointer to small buffer (rdx) (2) counter for small buffer (r8) (3) Size of small buffer (r9) (4) Counter for large buffer (rcx) (5) Pointer for large buffer (r15).  The register assignments are for optimization.

Comment: But anyway, if you want to unroll you could use aligned stores for all the 16-byte accesses.  e.g. `movaps` / `movsd` for the first 24-byte copy, then `movsd + movaps` for the 2nd 24-byte copy.  If the source data is always 16-byte aligned, though, then you'd need a `movups` load to load the 2nd and 3rd qwords.  Probably your best bet is just `movups` stores.  There is literally zero penalty for using `movups` when the pointer is in fact aligned at runtime, on Nehalem / Bulldozer and later.  And for contiguous stores, the store buffer should absorb most of the cost before commit to L1d.